# Transient method in Hibernate Search referencing proxy while MassIndexing

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am using a MassIndexer to index my documents. I have a method annotated with @Transient that references a lazily initialized @OneToMany collection like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "insertForeignKeyHere", referencedColumnName = "insertPrimaryKeyHere"),... })
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public Set<AdditionalOption> getAdditionalOptions() {
    return this.additionalOptions;
}

@Transient
@IndexedEmbedded
public Set<AdditionalOption> getActiveAdditionalOptions() {
    Set<AdditionalOption> ret = new HashSet<>();
    //the next line produces the error
    for (AdditionalOption addOpt : this.getAdditionalOptions()) {
        //do stuff.
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Whenever I try to Index this document with a MassIndexer and with no @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) I get this Exception:

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: <...>, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Any thoughts on how to do this without the EAGER fetching? (I have 4 or 5 collections that would need eager fetching if this didn't work differently -> HUGE performance problems)

Thanks in advance.

btw: I am using

```
<hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate.search.version>4.5.0.Alpha2</hibernate.search.version>
<lucene.version>3.6.2</lucene.version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using version *Hibernate Search 4.5.0.Final* : it looks like you're hitting [HSEARCH-1260](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1260), which we recently resolved.

Comment: When will the release be added to the maven repository at mvnrepository.org?

Comment: for now, I can use the jboss repo :).

Comment: The timing on that release was just brilliant for me :). Thanks mate. Btw, I am working on a nice addition to the Hibernate-Search API, can I send you an e-mail about it, so you can look at it, and tell me, whether pushing it is worth a try?

Comment: It seems this approach consumes too much memory on my system because the collections have an extraordinary size as it seems. I switched back to my approach because it doesn't consume as much memory as this. It even crashed my computer because it (the computer) ran out of memory.

Comment: I take that last comment back. I just had a bad fetch_size setting in my hibernate config.

Comment: Sure! please send suggestions on the API to the mailing list, or join us on IRC for chatting: http://hibernate.org/community/

Comment: I'm running into this issue on 5.3.0.Final. But on individual async index save that is marked with @Transactional

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other way on doing this, I will do it with this work-around (with different bean-classes than in the first posting). But I don't really like it.

```
public static FeatureValueRepository featureValueRepository;
private static final Lock featureValueRepositoryLock = new ReentrantLock();

private static FeatureValueRepository getFeatureValueRepository() {
    featureValueRepositoryLock.lock();
    try {
        if (featureValueRepository == null) {
            //ContextProvider is a custom class in our project
            featureValueRepository = ContextProvider.getContext().getBean(
                    FeatureValueRepository.class);
        }
        return featureValueRepository;
    } finally {
        featureValueRepositoryLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

And then call a method that queries by the root-bean's id.

Comment: this doesn't seem to get me much performance while indexing, tho.